# How to handle chinese characters in a query in mulesoft code

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I have a requirement where I am getting the data from a database from where am receiving the response as Chinese characters but am inserting those data into one more database and trying to retrieve the data from database while retrieving the data am getting ????? for those fields.

I do not have access to the database how to handle it in the mulesoft code.Please help.

"Ko": "??(??? ??)",
"CODE": "VGML",
"product": "Vegetarian meal (non-dairy)",
"kk": "?????????(??????????)"

Instead of question mark we need
"Ko": "아시아 채식 기내식",
"CODE": "AVML",
"product": "Asiatisches vegetarisches Gericht",
"kk": "アジア風ベジタリアンミール"
How can I resolve it mule code itself.

Connector am using is database connector- mysql version(7.4.1.jre8) db connector (1.8.2), tables am creating it like this "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order (Ko NVARCHAR(100),CODE NVARCHAR(5),product NVARCHAR(100), kk NVARCHAR(100)); I do not have access to the database I need to handle in my code itself.

Comment: You need to provide more details for others to be able to understand and replicate the issue. For example version of Mule runtime, version of connectors, JDBC drivers, queries, databases engines products and versions, any relevant encoding configurations in the databases, tables, connector configurations or in queries. The flow. Maybe some logging is also useful to see how data is being transformed. The operating system, version and default encoding, And even Java version.

Comment: Hi @HarshankBansal
Thank you for your response.
the database from where am receiving the date is Azure(Microsoft sql server)
database am pushing the data is mysql databse where chinese chars are getting converted to ??? marks.

Comment: Hi @aled
Thank you for your response too.
Sure I will provide you the details- the database from where am receiving the date is Azure(Microsoft sql server) database am pushing the data is mysql databse where chinese chars are getting converted to ??? marks.
Connector am using is database connector- mysql version(7.4.1.jre8) db connector (1.8.2), tables am creating it like this "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order (Ko NVARCHAR(100),CODE NVARCHAR(5),product NVARCHAR(100), kk NVARCHAR(100));
I do not have access to the database I need to handle in my code itself.
Please help.

Comment: @Avinash where have you hosted this app? Is it CloudHub? or a windows server? Are you getting the correct data from the source, i.e. SQL server?

Comment: @HarshankBansal it;s deployed on Cloudhub on yes am getting correct data from source.

Comment: Can you add the XML code of the `db:insert` and `db:select` connector?

Comment: adding xml code will be difficult for me.

Comment: adding xml code will be difficult for me.
As db:insert- insert into order ( `Ko`,`CODE`,`product`,`kk`) values ( :0,:1,:2,:3)
there is one select database connector with basic info passing insert query as payload.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like encoding issue. Can you put Transform Message before inserting to the MySQL database and apply `output application/json encoding = "UTF-8"`?

Comment: This might be better suited to a comment rather than an answer.